# visualization of paths

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Let's say, there are three classes: nodes, ports and cables.
A node has at least one port, a cable has exactly two ports.
Some ports are connected to exactly one other port each.
Like a network, where there are devices connected to each other, using their ports, going over cables, but some ports are not connected.

How can I visualize this in Wpf? I want to see for one node all ports and connected cables to other nodes, like:

```
Node1: port1 -> port2 -> Cable1 ->port3 ->port4 -> Node2
       port5 -> port6 -> Cable2 ->port7 ->port8 -> Cable3 ->port9 ->port10 -> Node3
       port3 -> *not connected*
```

Is it a good practice to create a new class, which contains two ports (one of the node and one of the cable) and a (cable or Node) and each node has a list of those new class' instances, for each cable one and for the node at the other and on. So this new class' instances can be used by a template, maybe by a hierarchical one? Or is it better to use the existing structure and create templates out of them, but it looks like, its going to be a very complex code in Wpf.

Edit:
The output shall be a table like above. I'm asking how it is possible to create such a table. Lets say, each node has its port in a *ObservableCollection* and all the other connections between the objects are realized as properties. Is it possible at all to show this table in wpf without using a *transport object*?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. I wouldn't recommend a solution where you have to duplicate objects just for presentation. Just write a function that iterates over every port, node and cable and get each of their "output".

It would go like this :

```
allObjects = all port, node and cable
for each object in allObjects
  for each output in object
     find output and link it with object
```

everything will be linked after that, the only problem that you have is to find a nice presentation layer, such as [maybe this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562927/free-and-open-source-wpf-chart-library), or any library that will allow you to show [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29). Graph in a mathematical sense, not in an excel, x-y axis graph

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I do not want to show the graph, I want to show all the connected nodes in a table, I'll edit the question.